# Как скрыть форму на странице после отправки post запроса с помощью js в шаблоне?

Tags: javascript, html-form

```html
<form method="post" action="" >
                {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="glow-on-hover" name="search" type="submit" onclick="this.classList.toggle('button--loading')" id="btnSubmit">
                <span class="button__text">Поиск</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="search" >
            </button>
            </form>
```

Я хочу скрыть форму, если пользователь уже нажал на кнопку. Я попытался использовать код JS, он работает хорошо, но после обновления страницы кнопка на форме остается действительной.  Мне нужно чтобы после отправки запроса форма скрывалась, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

ты можешь использовать cookie или если через JS то локальные переменные

[https://docs.retool.com/apps/web/guides/store-temporary-data#:~:text=Use%20localStorage.,sets%20rather%20than%20individual%20values](https://docs.retool.com/apps/web/guides/store-temporary-data#:%7E:text=Use%20localStorage.,sets%20rather%20than%20individual%20values).